# Call Audio Doesn't go through A2DP from Android to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Is there a way?

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, android, a2dp

I love the inbuilt feature that comes with 18.04 where you can simply stream audio from Android to Ubuntu if both the devices are connected over Bluetooth. Essentially, I can use my Linux desktop as Bluetooth speakers.
There's only one issue, in-call audio doesn't make use of this feature. If I'm in call or using any other app that uses telephony audio over music or notification (PUBG Mobile does this to enable voice chat within the game), Ubuntu does not receive that audio.

What modifications are needed to stream in-call audio to Ubuntu (and receive audio input from desktop's microphone)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

Two different Bluetooth profiles are needed and they can't be used simultaneously.

For what you want is HFP (mono + microphone) and what you've been using is correctly identified in the question,A2DP (stereo, no microphone).